# Recaptcha, Devise and Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, recaptcha

OS: Windows 8.1
Ruby 2.0
Rails 4.1
Devise 3.xx
recaptcha gem

I added recaptcha to the registrations/new.html.erb view:

```
<%= recaptcha_tags %>
```

And in the registrations controller:

```
      respond_to do |format|
        unless verify_recaptcha
          format.html { render :new, notice: t('registration_captcha_problem') }
          format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        else
          if @user.save
            format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: t('registration_successfully_created') }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

I also added

```
<%= recaptcha_tags %>
```

to the views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb

This is working fine. I am having an issue when I try to test the reset password link. The application crashes, with the following message:

```
undefined method `valid_captcha?' for #<Devise::PasswordsController:0x00000005e421b8>

block (2 levels) in <module:PasswordsControllerCaptcha>
devise_security_extension (0.8.0) lib/devise_security_extension/patches/passwords_controller_captcha.rb

module DeviseSecurityExtension::Patches

  module PasswordsControllerCaptcha

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do

      define_method :create do

        if valid_captcha? params[:captcha]

          self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(params[resource_name])

          if successfully_sent?(resource)

            respond_with({}, :location => new_session_path(resource_name))

          else

            respond_with(resource)
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Where do I process the response to the captcha validation? I don't have access to that controller.

Comment: Since I have the Devise security extensions installed, I needed to comment out anything with config.captcha_for_ from config/devise.rb. Once I did that, things worked fine